# Syntax error when using file operation functions in my codeigniter model

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm developing an ecommerce site using codeigniter. When I use file operation functions like fopen,fclose, It shows syntax error in model class. Anybody knows how to fix it ? I added "file" helper in autoload.php. I've checked the syntax error in both NetBeans and Dreamweaver. Here I add a sample class with the issue that I am facing,

```
<?php
Class amazon extends CI_Model
{
var $feed = <<<EOD
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>M_EXAMPLE_123456</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
  <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
  <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
        <SKU>INTRUG8888888</SKU>
        <StandardProductID>
          <Type>ASIN</Type>
          <Value>B0EXAMPLEG</Value>
        </StandardProductID>
        <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
        <ItemPackageQuantity>1</ItemPackageQuantity>
        <NumberOfItems>100</NumberOfItems>
        <DescriptionData>
          <Title>Balaji53444</Title>
          <Brand>TESTERCLOTHING</Brand>
          <Description><![CDATA[INTRUGTEST123 Test description of test product.]]></Description>
          <BulletPoint>Test 3 Meterial</BulletPoint>
          <MSRP currency="USD">0.10</MSRP>
          <Manufacturer></Manufacturer>
          <ItemType>example-item-type</ItemType>     
        </DescriptionData>
        <ProductData>
          <Clothing>
                 <VariationData>
                    <Parentage>child</Parentage>
                    <Size>Small</Size>
                    <Color>White</Color>
                    <VariationTheme>SizeColor</VariationTheme>
                 </VariationData>
                 <ClassificationData>
                    <ClothingType>Shirt</ClothingType>
                    <Department>Mens</Department>
                    <StyleKeywords>Apparel</StyleKeywords>
                    <ColorMap>White</ColorMap>
                    <InnerMaterial>White</InnerMaterial>
                    <OuterMaterial>White</OuterMaterial>
                    <Season>All Seasons</Season>
                    <CollarType>Crew</CollarType>
                    <SleeveType>Short</SleeveType>
                    <IsAdultProduct>false</IsAdultProduct>
                 </ClassificationData>
          </Clothing>
        </ProductData>
   </Product>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
EOD;

var $marketplaceIdArray = array("Id" => array('A333NV4543ZUPX1J3X'));
var $feedHandle = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');

}
?>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please update the screenshot with a higher resolution one, text is unreadable. With a mouse-over tooltip or copy-paste an error message

Comment: try to replace <<<EOD with "

Comment: the code snippet above is what's in the screenshot, I have good eyes ;)

Comment: I replaced. but still error is there.

Comment: But what's the error message? It should appear when hovering the line

Comment: @Vlakarados : I added error message also.

Comment: The general practice in codeigniter is that you do not close the php tag in controllers nor models as the output is always buffered

Answer (score 0):

fopen is not codeigniter function but it is php core function. Please execute this file via PHP as your code does not seem to have any syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

what is that `var`? :)

`var` is deprecated in PHP 5. Remove that var, and it won't give error.

change the end of your file as below: (or simply remove `var`)

```
$marketplaceIdArray = array("Id" => array('A333NV4543ZUPX1J3X'));
$feedHandle = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');
```

Comment: var is used in codeigniter member variables.  I already tested without var,@ etc bro. But still the error appears.

Comment: var is deprecated in PHP 5. That is why you get error. Remove that var and it will work.